# How to include VTK on paraview plugin?

Tags: cmake, vtk, paraview

I've managed to build `paraview` from source on OSX using clang.

Now I need to build a plugin with `CMakeList.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)

SET(PLUGIN_NAME GeoPhysics)
SET(PLUGIN_VERSION "1.1")

FIND_PACKAGE(ParaView REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${PARAVIEW_USE_FILE})

ADD_PARAVIEW_PLUGIN(${PLUGIN_NAME} ${PLUGIN_VERSION}
    SERVER_MANAGER_XML Server.xml
    SOURCES
                    BaseGeoPhysicsHDF5SphericalReader.cxx
    SERVER_MANAGER_SOURCES
                    vtkGeoPhysicsHDF5Reader.cxx
                    vtkGeoPhysicsHDF5SphericalReader.cxx
                    vtkMakeGeoEarth.cxx
                    vtkProjMap.cxx
    GUI_RESOURCE_FILES GeoPhysics.xml GeoPhysics-GUI.xml
)
```

So I `export ParaView_DIR=$HOME/projects/ParaView/build`, but `make` can't find `VTK` headers.

> ~/Geophysics/plugin/vtkMakeGeoEarth.cxx:11:10: fatal
>   error: 'vtkGlobeSource.h'
>         file not found

`vtkGlobeSource.h` is located in `$HOME/projects/ParaView/VTK/Geovis/Core`

How should I add `VTK` on the `CMakeList.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

The `vtkGeovisCore` is not enabled in the default ParaView build. Make sure you turn on the module by enabling the cmake flag `Module_vtkGeovisCore`.

Comment: Rebuilding Paraview with Geoviscore didn't help

Comment: Are you getting the same error or a different error when `Module_vtkGeovisCore` is enabled? Also, are you setting `ParaView_DIR` when configuring your plugin in CMake? I'm not sure that setting the environment variable will work - if it does, you at least need to run CMake again after setting it in your shell.

Comment: It's the same error `'vtkGlobeSource.h' file not found` even giving the full path to the build directory. Inside `build/VTK/Geovis/Core` there is only `vtkGeovisCoreModule.h`

Comment: It seems that the option  `PARAVIEW_INSTALL_DEVELOPMENT_FILES` is not available on Mac OSX or Windows.